# Is it possible to open multiple infoWindows for one marker in google maps api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I am working on a project, and they want to look the infowindows like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

How is this possible and which library would you recommend?

Comment: The question would be do you want multiple info windows for one marker or multiple markers?

Comment: Multiple infowindow for one marker

Comment: I see there only 1 element which I would call "InfoWindow" ....the red Box may be implemeted via a custom Overlay(e.g. [InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html)) , the other boxes via [custom controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls)

Comment: The right white element will also be a infowindow that shows more information about the marker.

Comment: @Dr.Molle did you use infoBox? Because it is position differently when iam zooming..

Comment: None of these elements is a `google.maps.infoWindow`

Comment: How should you recommend it to do? The one above the house with infobox and the on the right side make a div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google maps v3 it is possible by creating custom event listeners and modifying autocentering. Examples can be found here: http://you.arenot.me/2010/06/29/google-maps-api-v3-0-multiple-markers-multiple-infowindows/

Several infowindows for one marker (not tested):

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position:latLng,
  map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(content){
  return function(){
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
    infowindow2.setContent(content+'222');
    infowindow2.open(map, this);
  }
}(content));
```